# How can I get the value of Window ID?

Tags: recordmydesktop

When recording a specific window by recordmydesktop, what should I do for investigating "windowid" specified as a "windowid" option?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
xwininfo -display :0
```

Comment: My display was :1.  `xwininfo` by itself worked

Comment: Probably because it defaults to -display :0.

Comment: @ElijahLynn Nope. It defaults to `$DISPLAY` like every other X client.

Comment: [Check out also `wmctrl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12469119/4970442)

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative, you can use this one-liner:

```
recordmydesktop --windowid `xwininfo -display :0 | grep 'id: 0x' | grep -Eo '0x[a-z0-9]+'`
```

Comment: This is brilliant! In my case, I had to omit `-display :0`

Answer (score 4):

`xwininfo -name "recordmydesktop"`