# Very poor performance after  downloading Kazam screencaster

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, video

I wanted to do some fullscreen video recording to demonstrate some software I was using.

I downloaded Kazam screencaster but the performance is really bad.

I recorded 30 seconds of video but it locks up and I basically have about 4 frames in the entire file. I am using the default options but this happens every time.

**Is there anything I can do to get better performance?**

My laptop runs with 4GB memory. Has anyone else had similar problems?

**Can anyone be recommend an alternative?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **Recordmydesktop** which is available in the Ubuntu Software Centre and came highly recommended to me. I have been using it extensively and have created over 50 screen casts with no issues. Its simple to use and intuitive.

As to the performance of your system and whether Kazam is causing it is questionable as it could be any number of things.

Also, take a look at this question ([how can I improve overall system performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)) as it may help you with your performance issues

---

Linked Question:

- [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that can cause slow video recording. One possible candidate is the Compiz compositing engine used by unity. You can avoid Compiz by using Unity2D as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D

Comment: I dont use unity I use gnome

Comment: Are you running compiz?