# What are the best Screencasting tools?

Tags: screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a screencast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

Please i wanna know (people whom have tried) which sceencast tool is the best.
For me i've tried kazam but i still unconvinced totally with this choice. i need your expert please. 
***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Kazam is one of the best. There has been some changes in the latest version.   For all the changes, you may look at [Three Wise Men](http://www.twm-kd.com/category/linux/kazam/)

> Kazam is a simple screen recording program that will capture the
>   content of your screen and record a video file that can be played by
>   any video player that supports VP8/WebM video format.<sup>1</sup>

To install Kazam, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/stable-series
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install kazam
> ```

Also take a look at [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Friendship with Linux](http://indrajeet-deshmukh.blogspot.com/2012/04/9best-screencasting-tool-for-ubuntu.html)</sup>

Comment: @Mitch... thanks i've already tried kazam and recordMyDesktop and also istanboul and others much but i just wanna know an expert opinion