# Mouse arrow flash and ghost in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: graphics, mouse

In previous Ubuntu's version 13.04 it worked fine, but now in Saucy the mouse pointer has strange effects.

Using an *Asus K53SV*

Comment: Please add more details to your question. If you can, [record a video](http://askubuntu.com/q/4428/62483) showing the effects and upload to YouTube and then link it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turm off the secound screen is System settings > Displays ; it is marked with pink rentagle; Click on it and bottom is enable/disable botton

Answer (score 0):

go to system settings>Displays and turn the Unknown Display off. it worked for me !