# Is there an app for screen recoding with PIP (picture in picture)

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast

I'm looking for a screencast software that can record my screen and my face (using my webcam) in a Picture-in-picture (you know, that secondary video in a small rectangle in the corner of the screen).

Comment: 2019 says use

Open Broadcaster

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webcam studio](https://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/).

[image]

Some of the features include:

- Switch webcams on a single click
- Show an IRC channel in your video broadcast
- Broadcast your desktop for creation of nice HOWTO's
- Be creative and put animations and banners
- Display what song is currently played by Rhythmbox
- Co-host a remote friend, show his webcam inside your output
  (PicInPic)
- Connect to WeatherBug and display your current weather
- Apply some fancy effects on each source
- Have a green wall, then why not use the ChromaKey effect to do the
  same as the weather man on the news network
- Use all kinds of devices as webcamera like a MiniDV, your iPhone,
  etc....

[image]

Download from [here](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/webcamstudio/WebcamStudio4Linux/0.56/webcamstudio_0.56_all.deb)

[source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/)

---

Another way is to use the **Gnome Mplayer**

you can install by:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mplayer
```

This command will show the window of the webcam output while screencasting so any screencast software you can use can also screencast your webcam output so you don't need other software to merge.

```
mplayer -cache 128 -tv driver=v4l2:width=176:height=177 -vo xv tv:// -noborder -geometry "95%:93%" -ontop
```

Please watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcGQ3kOn6Is) to demonstarte how to use gnome-mplayer in screencasting with webcam window enabled

[How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) : List of screencast software for Ubuntu( Personally I advise you kazam)

Comment: No longer maintained

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `kazam`

you can install by:

```
pip install kazam
```