# Looking for software with picture in picture for streaming

Tags: software-recommendation, video-streaming

Any good software for multi-cam streaming?

Should I trust [this build](https://launchpad.net/~webcamstudio/+archive/ubuntu/webcamstudio-dailybuilds)?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webcamstudio/webcamstudio-dailybuilds
```

Is there any Ubuntu application which support *picture in picture*?

Comment: I think it's safe. There's a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429652/is-there-an-app-for-screen-recoding-with-pip-picture-in-picture

Comment: VLC does PIP playback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently started using OBS, it has been around for quite some time though. It supports multiple overlays, so p-in-p is no problem from 2 cams.

[https://obsproject.com/](http://obsproject.com)

It is a breeze to use, seems to be a relatively defacto piece of software various youtubers are using, and is really quite easy to use with lots of tutorials on youtube.