# Where can I see the text that is displayed during boot?

Tags: boot, log

During boot, there are three stages :

1. Before grub, I have two lines of text flashing telling me that something is not found
2. Then there is the grub menu
3. Then there is the normal boot process

On ubuntu server 12.04 LTS, in which log can I find all the text that's displayed during stage 1 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can find stage 1 through Linux. If it appears *before* grub it has nothing to do with your installed OS. You might be able to find it in your BIOS's logs.

As for stage 3, you can find that text in `/var/log/boot.log`. For example, here are the 1st 20 lines of mine (yours will be different of course):

```
$ head -20 /var/log/boot.log 
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
resume: libgcrypt version: 1.5.3
[e4rat-preload] Open /var/lib/e4rat/startup.log ... 
[e4rat-preload] 6693 files scanned
[e4rat-preload] Pre-loading I-Nodes ...
[e4rat-preload] Execute `/sbin/init' ...
[e4rat-preload] Pre-loading file content ...
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[info] Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
[e4rat-preload] Successfully transferred files into page cache
[ ok ] Reading early boot files....
[ ok ] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done.
[ ok ] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...done.
[ ok ] Activating swap...done.
[....] Checking root file system...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda7: clean, 581416/4505600 files, 6554372/18013696 blocks
done.
[ ok ] Activating lvm and md swap...done.
[....] Checking file systems...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I don't know if it appears before grub launches. All I can tell, is that it appears a fraction of second before grub displays its menu.

Comment: @Adeline in that case it's before GRUB. It is most likely a message about a disk not found. Perhaps you have changed your hardware and the BIOS hasn't realized? In any case, all messages that appear before you chosen your OS in GRUB have nothing to do with the OS. Linux (or any other OS) only comes into play _after_ you've chosen it from GRUB, anything before that is BIOS. The only exception would be a grub error.

Comment: What I did: in a vmware virtual machine, I installed 12.04 LTS, after partitioning the disk the same way that on my dedicated web server. Then I used TAR to replicate my web server on my virtual machine (thus overwriting the virtual machine). People told me it was possible to perform full backup with tar. Everything is working fine, except for this message displayed. Also, just after grub, I have a message `ERROR: no such device: 8cc49b36-64c9-……. press a key to continue…..`

Comment: @Adeline OK, and is there a problem? If your machine is booting correctly, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yes. Except, that's the way I have selected to backup my only and one production web server, in case the disk crashes. I wouldn't want my backup not to work when I need it, or to create a fragile OS install when restored… So, I wish to investigate the issue. What's happening? How can I fix it? Is it related to disk UIDS?

Comment: @Adeline you might be hitting [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=817187). There is a workaround suggested in the comments. I can't find where grub logs its errors and I'm beginning to think it doesn't. Since this is a VM, you could cheat and simply [record your desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/4428/85695) while it is booting and then play back the recording slowly to read the error message.