# How to recording movie from website (screen desktop and sound capture)?

Tags: sound

Please show me the way on ubuntu to record ScreenDesktop with sound **not from microphone** (**sound from movie/video** on website) -  the same function with WM Capture software on Windows.

Thank so much

Comment: There are already multiple threads about this subject, e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `audacity` to record the sound, and `Kazam` from the software centre for the video.