# Screen recording with ring buffer

Tags: screencast

Is there any screen recording software which can record to ring buffer? I'd like to have a recording of the last 10-15 minutes happening in some window.

To be more concrete, I want to this application to be "always" running. At any point in time, I want be able to retrieve a recording of what happend in the last 10 minutes. As I don't want my disk to fill up, the size of the recorded file should limited. On the other hand, the recording should never stop (i.e., if the size limit is reached, throw away the beginning of the recording).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a screencast?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)

Comment: It is possible that one of the tools in the answers to this question offers to option to record into a ring buffer -- but whether one of them (and which) does so, is not answered there.

Comment: **Promising-looking answer:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373143/how-can-i-record-my-desktop-into-a-replay-buffer-so-i-can-replay-the-last-x-s/373148