# How to record screen in video to report bugs in Ubuntu interface?

Tags: video, screen

I would like to find some standard way of recording my screen, since I would like to report some bugs in the user interface and its typing system with Dvorak keyboard layout. 
The cursor location is unstable in many locations. 
I would like to find some community guidelines how you want video to be recorded.

How can you record screen in video suitable for reporting bugs in Ubuntu interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several caveats in video recording, editing and conversion to in Ubuntu. 
Please, see the thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/770165/25388). Shortly, do for the

```
sudo apt-get install kazam openshot ffmpeg
```

In video editing started in Kazam, Ignore other video editing software because bugs or not in apt-get. 
Use `ffmpeg` to convert the recorded .mp4 file to .gif.

Answer (score 0):

To take a screenshot, you can use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), gnome-screenshot etc

To record a video of the desktop, you can use  [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net), [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam), [Istanbul Desktop Session Recorder](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul) etc

Comment: I am about video recording. Any standard tool for Ubuntu so I can embed the video here, not too large?

Comment: To record a video of the desktop, you can use RecordMyDesktop, Kazam, Istanbul Desktop Session Recorder etc.  These can be installed via software centre

Comment: Nothing by default? Any specific details by the community for videos?

Comment: Please check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast