# How to Convert/Edit .mp4 file to .gif in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, video, image-processing

I would like to do this by default tools and scripting. 
The logic is just to take pictures from the video and store them in the .gif format.

### Editing

Do `sudo apt-get install kazam pitivi openshot` for test video. 
I record a video and get

[image]

- I Choose `Edit with` Pitivi, and Press Continue. Fails. Bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pitivi/+bug/1594088) because of python3/gst-python dependency fails.
- I choose `Edit with` Openshot, and Press Continue. GUI opens. Just drag the video to the bottom and add cuts. It works.
- Avidemux not available in apt-get. I sent an email about the thing to the developer of Avidemux.

  [image]

### Conversion and Resizing

Do `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` for the conversion tool.

Resize. If .mp4, downsample by 50%

```
# http://askubuntu.com/questions/160869/need-to-downsample-video-to-a-lower-resolution
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=iw/2:-1 output.mp4
```

Convert from .mp4 to .gif

```
ffmpeg -i ScreencastOfKazam.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 outputYes.gif
```

Resize. If .gif, use the tool [ezgif.com/resize](http://ezgif.com/resize) because I could not find a one-liner for it. TODO

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, Debian 8.5
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid, Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: There is no default way but here's quite a good answer using **ffmepg**: http://askubuntu.com/a/110320/3940

Comment: Please, offer an example about the command too here. I think this kind of task should be able to be done with scripting. I may be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create animated GIF images of a screencast?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

Comment: Could you please move your answer inside the question to a proper answer? You can even accept your own answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "default" you mean that you want to use integrated software, just printscreen frame by frame and then stich them together.

In GIMP, for the stich part, you need to open all the images as layers and then Filters > Animation > Playback... and modify them the options that you need.

Comment: That it is not enough. It should be a script that does it to you. Record frames from the video in a loop, and makes .gif image.

Comment: Why "there should be"? I have never used it, nor know anybody who would. if you want something more automated, install and use `ffmpeg` as explained in the comments above :)

Comment: Yes, `ffmpeg` is the best solution here. There is some bug with its first editing tool i.e. pitivi. Please, see the body. Can you confirm?