# Gameplay screen recorder for Ubuntu?

Tags: video, games, desktop-recording

Are there any gameplay screen recorders out there for Ubuntu?

I intend to use it for Urban Terror recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that I use and love for game-play recording is SimpleScreenRecorder.

[image]

It's low on resource-use, and records video and sound, and as its name suggests it's very simple to use.

To install simpleScreenRecorder go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

**note** if you want to record 32-bit OpenGL applications on a 64-bit system run this command too:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

**Note2** the openGL recorder is still experimental but runs very smoothly and with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for a gameplay recorder, you should search for a screen recorder. Here's a good one:

[`gkt-recordmydesktop`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gtk-recordmydesktop/) -- audio and video capture

Related: [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)