# Most lightweight screen recorder/caster software?

Tags: 16.04, games, screencast

I have been trying recently many screen recorders, since I want to record Age of Empires 2 HD matches.

Since I have to use wine to run the game, there's already a significant overhead and performance hit on the game's fps rates. So I'd like to know what would you say is the lightest screen recorder in order to reduce as much as possible the performance hit. The best I've tested so far is Kazam, which is taking quite a bit of fps (almost half) and even using ffmpeg and pulse from the command line result in even worse performance.

I am recording full hd and I have an i5-5200u processor with Intel HD 5500 graphics. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I have tried so far Kazam, Simplescreenrecorder, RecordmyDesktop, ScreenStudio, OBS and FFmpeg via command line. The best performer so far has been Kazam.

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-record-my-screen?rq=1) on many alternatives

Comment: Thanks. I have tried many applications already, and all of them work. However what I'm looking for is to know if anyone has a suggestion for a very lightweight one, since everything I've tried so far takes a very big toll in game performance.

Comment: Have you tried [OBS](https://obsproject.com/download) ?

Comment: I did, it brings my system to a crawl. It's very feature rich but my system takes the higest hit from it.

Comment: I have used VLC in the past, but have not compared it to Kazam.

Comment: Which `ffmpeg` command have you used? ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mkv

Answer (score 1):

A hardware option, such as an HDMI (or other compatible) video recorder can simultaneously record your screen without affecting system performance.

Hardware isn't a software solution, and yet it is the most "lightweight screen recorder".

Comment: Thanks, but that's out of my budget currently. Software wise, kazam has given me the best results. It seems weird to me that command line scripts with ffmpeg aren't performing better.

Comment: Yeah. Software recording essentially competes with games for key resources: CPU, motherboard bus bandwidth, HD i/o etc.