# How to change screencast duration in GNOME 3 screen recorder?

Tags: gnome, screencast

I want to change the length of my screencast recorded with the GNOME 3 Screen Recorder from the default 30 seconds to 30 minutes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Open the `dconf-editor`
2. Find `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys` in the tree of settings
3. Find the setting named `max-screencast-length` (the default value is 30 seconds)
4. Change it to 600 seconds for 10 minutes (10 * 60 seconds), or 1800 seconds for 30 minutes (30 * 60 seconds)
   [image: max-screencast-]

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length 1800
```

Which will set the maximum screencast length to 1800 seconds, which is what you want!  **;-)**