# Ubuntu 16.10 failing to update

Tags: updates, ppa, update-manager, 16.10

I am trying to update my ubuntu with the fillowing command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But everytime it fails and gives following error -

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/byzanz/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/byzanz/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So far i tried every solution given on this website but none of them worked.
The prolem started when i tried to install Byzanz software to record my screen by following the steps given in this link - [How can I record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen)

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: 16.10 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to or install a supported release.

Comment: I'm sorry but you asking a question about an Ubuntu distribution which has reached already its end of lifetime. You might want to consider upgrading. I'm voting to close the question therefore as off-topic because its about an EOL release of Ubuntu. But to not let your post be in vain i opted for voting it to be a duplicate, so it helps other find the information straight away you where struggling to find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens due do a connection problem or something else gone wrong (i.e. this repository does not have a release file because there might be no version for 16.10 build maybe). However you can remove this repository by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:fossfreedom/byzanz
```

This will turn the update process back to normal and remove the entry from your `sources.list` file.